# Restheart Aggregation Framework - Optional Avars?

Tags: restheart

We have an aggregation query in RestHeart which works well.

In the `match` section, we allow users to specify a specific document Id, to return just that document:

```
                "_$match" : {
                    "_id" : {
                        "_$var" : "n"
                    },
```

However, we've also like users to be able to omit this, and get all documents in the collection.

Is there any way to make `avars` optional, or to specify a wildcard for that `avar`? Currently if the user omits the avar, they get an error. And setting the `avar` to null or an empty string literally matches those values.

I guess another alternative would be if there can be conditional logic in the aggregation query properties -- not sure if this is possible.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1):

I have found a simpler solution. The aggregation query in the _properties collection can be kept as-is, but instead, a wildcard can be specified in the GET request. Here is an example:

```
GET https://test.restheartapi.com:4443/DataBase/collection/_aggrs/items?avars={"n":/.*/, "m":/.*/ }
```

... So although it isn't possible to make avars optional in RestHeart, it's still possible to specify a wildcard as the value.

I'm not sure if there's a small performance hit by using a regular expression like this, but it seems to be the only simple way to do this for now.

Comment: hi im not able to send /.*/ from javascript. it is getting replaced by {}(empty object). can you please help?

Comment: Re: sending /.*/ from javascript. This is probably interpreted as a regexp by javascript; so I think it would need to be escaped. You could try quoting it, or else using backslashes before each special character, to escape - like:

\/.*\/

Answer (score -1):

You can have a conditional aggregation using the [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator

> Evaluates a boolean expression to return one of the two specified return expressions.
>
> The $cond expression has one of two syntaxes:
>
> `{ $cond: { if: <boolean-expression>, then: <true-case>, else: <false-case-> } }`
>
> Or:
>
> `{ $cond: [ <boolean-expression>, <true-case>, <false-case> ] }`

Comment: Perfect --- thanks! So in my use case, if the user gives a value for the "n" avar, then I went to include it in the match.

If they don't give a value (which I guess means I'll need to pass an empty string, so ReSTHeart doesn't give an error), then I want to not include that in the match string.

I think I'll probably need to do that using Regular expresions:

$match: {
   _id: {
        "$cond": {
              if: { $eq: [ {_$var" : "n"}, "" ] }, then:  "/.*/", else: {_$var" : "n"}
        }
    }
}

Does that look right --- or is there a way to do this without using a regex?

Comment: I have looked further at this, and the $cond operator doesn't seem to be supported in the match section, so I don't think this solution is going to work. I have come up with an alternative using regular expressions (see below)